# HTML table with nested td

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add 3 columns under `'Top 10'` table header but when I add values for cells everything gets corrupt
also there's an empty cell just before the 'ID' cell, I don't know where it came from

```
<html>
       <head>
          <title>ss</title>
          <style>
             table { width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; }
             td { border: 1px solid #000; }
          </style>
       </head>
       <body>
          <center>
             <table border="1">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                   <th align="center">
                      <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"></font>
                   </th>
                   <th align="center">
                      <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Site</font>
                   </th>
                   <th colspan="4" align="center">
                      <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Top 10</font>
                   </th>
                </tr>
             </thead>

        <!-- Table Content -->
        <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td align="center">
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">1</font>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">example</font>
        </td>
        <td>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td >Name</td>
            <td>From</td>
       </td>
    </tr>

       </tbody>
             </table>
          </center>
       </body>
    </html>
```

your help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML of your table is completely off. Make sure you use the right elements and close everything too. And try to apply styling with CSS as much as possible.

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td,
th {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Site</th>
            <th colspan="3">Top 10</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">1</td>
            <td rowspan="2">Example</td>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>From</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Kobo</td>
            <td>Jack</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you, but how to add cells under ID,Name,From? example 1, kobo, jack

Comment: You can do so by applying rowspan to the first two columns. I updated the answer on your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

you really need to read html specification, font and center tags have several years obsolete, you need to use CSS instead

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>ss</title>
        <style>
            body {font: "Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif"}
            table { width: 90%; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 0 auto;}
            td { border: 1px solid #000; }
            td.center, th { text-align: center;}
        </style>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Header 1</th>
                    <th>Header 2</th>
                    <th colspan="4">Header 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- Table Content -->
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="center">Cell 1</td>
                    <td class="center">Cell 2</td>
                    <td>Cell 3</td>
                    <td>Cell 4</td>
                    <td>Cell 5</td>
                    <td>Cell 6</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```